# How to stop Windows Services via Powershell with AutomaticDelayed start type?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I was able to write a Powershell 2.0 script that that stops certain running services, which I use in an Ansible script. The Ansible script reboots the VM first, then runs the script.

```
# Get a list of running XYZ_* services and store them in an array.
$runningExaServices = Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*XYZ_*"} | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"}

# Iterate throgh the services and stop all of them except EXA_Web,
# EXA_Web_APIs, EXA_Nginx, EXA_Redis. We'll stop those separately
Foreach($service in $runningExaServices) {
    Write-Host "Stopping: "$service.name
    Stop-Service -Name $service.name -Force
    $svc = Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $service.name}
    Write-Host $svc.name: $svc.status
}
```

The `XYZZ_*` services will indeed stop. However, the services with `Automatic (Delayed Start)` would start running again. What's the secret to keeping them stopped? TIA

Answer (score 0):

Since `Get-Service` doesn't expose the "*Automatic (Delayed start)*" configuration, you'll have to rely on just the *Automatic* value for `StartType`. If you want them to stay stopped, switch the `starttype` value to "*Manual*":

```
# Get a list of running XYZ_* services and store them in an array.
$runningExaServices = Get-Service -Name "*XYZ_*" | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"} #| Stop-Service -PassThru

Foreach($service in $runningExaServices) {
    #Write-Host "Stopping: $($service.name)"
    if ($service.StartType -eq "Automatic") {
        $Serice | Set-Service -StartupType 'Manual'
    }
    Stop-Service -Name $service.name -Force -PassThru
    # Write-Host "$($svc.name): $($svc.status)"
}
```

I'm not too sure when these cmdlets were introduced but, I will go ahead and take a guess that `Set-Service` was released at the same time as `Get-Service`; i.e. PowerShell 2.0.

With that said, a simple `if` condition/statement can check for the `starttype` value and proceed accordingly by setting it to "*Manual*". Then, stopping the service(s).

---

Couple of side notes:

- You don't need the loop if you pipe directly to `Set-Service`, and `Stop-Service` given the following circumstances:

  - *You don't care about setting the `starttype` to "Manual"*
  - *You don't care about the iteration process, and just having them all stop at once with a `-PassThru` switch provided; which in turn outputs the object with the new status of "*Stopped*"*.
- Lastly, - *referring back to the 2nd sub-bullet point above* - `-PassThru` is what I would **suggest** rather than stating what current service object you're on and re-querying the same object for the new status.

Comment: The "delayed start" thing isn't a separate start type, although the GUI presents it as such; it's a separate boolean flag. While `Get-Service` does not expose it, the more complete `Win32_Service` WMI class does (`Get-WmiObject Win32_Service | Select Name, StartMode, DelayedAutoStart`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thank you for that. As soon as I posted my answer, I checked out `Win32_Service` and found it there as well. Will adjust my answer accordingly depending on what the OP's feedback says.